# Adding large source folder to Matlab path produces error

Tags: matlab

I have a folder with collection of several packages and modules that I have developed or collected over the years. The number of files is of the order 5k organized  in the folder. When ever I want to add this folder in to the Matlab path , I receive the following error:

```
Error in ischar (line 2)
y = strcmp(typeof(x), 'string');

Error in cell/strcat (line 22)
    if ischar(varargin{i}),

Error in uiopen (line 63)
    allML(1)=strcat(allML(1), ';*.mdl');
```

I have to close Matlab to continue proper operation. Once I close Matlab, I don't have the folder that I added in the path included in the path. If I repeat the process the same scenario happens. 
 I am using Matlab 2011b version. Can anyone explain why it happens and what is the work around? Is there any limit to number of files I can add to the Matlab path ?

Comment: Are you adding with the UI or via `addpath`?

Comment: It seems that one of your file causes the error: matlab does not recognise the file name as a valid string.

Comment: @Magla, Kind of... it's any file really since the problem is with `ischar`.  See my answer below. This is why I asked about UI vs. `addpath`.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb... Are you using the Fessler Image reconstruction toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

Look for something that is redefining `ischar` in that folder full of files.  Maybe an `ischar.m` in a folder starting with "@"?  Or maybe it is already redefined.  Try,

```
which -all ischar
```

What tips me off is that there is *no code* in MATLAB's `ischar.m`.  Line 2 reading,

```
y = strcmp(typeof(x), 'string');
```

does not exist in the `ischar.m` of MathWorks' MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a strange character in the directory, to verify this please navigate to it and check:

```
d = dir;
unique([d.name])
```

From this you can experiment to find out which character is causing the problem, and choose whether you want to exclude the file, or rename it.

---

Perhaps even more efficiently, but untried:

Use `dbstop if error` and try to add the path. Now you should be able to navigate to the workspace of `uiopen` and find out directly which file is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines of code are from the "ischar.m" function in the freemat/pre-3.5 subdirectory of Fessler's image reconstruction toolbox.  That directory should be in the path *only* when using and old version of freemat.  It should not be in the path when using matlab or octave.  Do not just add all of the folders into the path; instead put the top level directory in your path and then run the "setup.m" to set the appropriate directories for your situation, just like the readme says!